# Convert Flux<T> in Mono<Response<T>> in Spring Webflux

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

We are using Spring Data reactive and when we call `findAll` we are receiving a `Flux<T>` and we want to expose this response in the API, but our API structure is

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "items": [ ... ]
}
```

So, we want to expose this as `Mono<<Response<T>>`

```
public class Response<T> {
    private int status;
    private List<T> items;
    // ...
}
```

How to convert `Flux<T>` in `Mono<Response<T>>` in Spring Webflux?

Comment: Its not clear if you want `Mono<<Response<T>>` or `Mono<List<T>>`. To get the second, you can invoke `Flux#collectList`.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat thank you, I've edited the question, yes I want to convert to `Mono<<Response<T>>`

Comment: @user13674325 You still want to use `collectList()` to grab a `Mono<List<T>>` - you can then just map that result to your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Flux<User> users = //...
Mono<Response<User>> response = users.collectList().map(items -> new Response(items));
```